# a continuous 20000 km-long chain of encounters (or "people")

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-request, expressions, translation, french

Is this sentence understandable?

> a continuous 20000 km-long chain of encounters (or "people")

in french that would be :

> Une chaine interrompue de rencontre sur 20 000 km.

("Chaine" in this context means a continuous string of events linked to each others. Each encounter would be a link of this long chain), (or "string?).

**Context:**

I need this sentence to present a social experiment that consist of encountering people during a 20000 km walk. The idea is to show a continuity of the chain : a "chain" of encounters (a lot of people and culture) from the beginning to the end. Chain is in itself continuous but the mean idea is to highlight the continuity (it could have been several little chains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "a chain of consecutive personal encounters spanning 20,000km"

(it might be better to also specify the time component of this chain of events, e.g. "20,000km and three months"

Answer (score 2):

The word your looking for in English is *series*.

A 20,000km series of encounters.

Answer (score 2):

You are having a series of encounters on your 20K walk.  You wish to think of each encounter as a link in a long chain that extends for the entire length of your walk.

> The idea is to show a continuity of the chain

We [more often write](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(unbroken%20chain)%2C(continuous%20chain)&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28unbroken%20chain%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28continuous%20chain%29%3B%2Cc0) an *unbroken* chain rather than "continuous".